# AWK:: How to remove the "space" characters thats exists after each word using awk

Tags: regex, awk, sed

My Sample Text:

Please copy paste the following 7 lines in notepad.  So that you can see there are spaces after each word. (Please note: number of spaces are not constant. In some place there are 16 spaces, and with no space also)

```
Gadu-Gadu                
Gadu-Gadu_file-transfer  
Gadu-Gadu_server
Gadu-Gadu_video          
Gadu-Gadu_voice          
GameKit
Generic\ Voice
```

For example I have 16 spaces between "Gadu-Gadu and Gadu-Gadu_file-transfer".

I want to remove the spaces, Then i want output as:

```
Gadu-Gadu
Gadu-Gadu_file-transfer
Gadu-Gadu_server
Gadu-Gadu_video
Gadu-Gadu_voice
GameKit
Generic\ Voice
```

NOTE : There is a space between "Generic\ Voice". This should not be removed by script. I want to remove only spaces that exists at the end of each word.

Please suggest me any awk or other programming script to achive this.

Thanks,

Kumar

Comment: did you want to remove all the trailing spaces? If yes, then this `sed 's/ \+$//' file` would do that job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk`, this should do:

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' file
Gadu-Gadu
Gadu-Gadu_file-transfer
Gadu-Gadu_server
Gadu-Gadu_video
Gadu-Gadu_voice
GameKit
Generic\ Voice
```

Or just removing trailing spaces:

```
awk '{sub(/ +$/,"")}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do this through sed like,

```
$ sed '/^.\{25\}$/s/ \+$//' file
Gadu-Gadu
Gadu-Gadu_file-transfer
Gadu-Gadu_server
Gadu-Gadu_video
Gadu-Gadu_voice
GameKit
Generic\ Voice
```

The above command would remove all the spaces which are at the last only on the lines which has exactly 25 characters.

To remove all the spaces at the end, irrespective of no of characters present on that particular line.

```
sed 's/ \+$//' file
```

Add inline-edit parameter `-i` to save the changes made.

```
sed -i 's/ \+$//' file
```

Answer (score 1):

by awk, it can be shorter.

```
awk '$1=$1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/[ \s\t]+$//g' File
```

Substituting the trailing spaces or tabs in each line with nothing.